# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /usr/local/bin/chromedriver_linux64

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, github, junit, selenium-chromedriver

Selenium scripts are running fine when i am trying to run via eclipse but it is throwing error if I am running via Jenkins.

Error in Jenkins console log : java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /usr/local/bin/chromedriver_linux64

Comment: If you do an ls in usr/local/bin, there is the chromdriver_linux64?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the driver executable as in linux/mac machines, the driver is not executable by default.

You can make the driver executable by first going to its location, in this case it would be like:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
```

And then you need to make it executable like:

```
chmod +x chromedriver_linux64
```

Comment: Hi Sameer, Thanks for your reply! Currently the permission is rwxr-xr-r and I hope it has executable permission.